# Airflow xcom_pull pickle exhausted before end of frame

Tags: python, pickle, airflow

I am performing an xcom_pull on an http response (as a dictionary) I previously xcom_push'ed
and receive `pickle exhausted before end of frame`.

For http responses that result in a shorter dictionary, I don't get this error.

Is this a limitation to what can be xcom_pull/push'ed?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem or a very similar one.  We're using a MySQL DB for Airflow.  It occurs after an xcom_pull() and the trace goes through sqlalchemy.  A deeper dive into the DB suggests that the pickle is being stored in the dag_pickle.pickle column as blob, which has a max size of 65,535 bytes.

For us, a couple table adjustments fixed the problem:

```
alter table dag_pickle modify pickle MEDIUMBLOB;
alter table xcom modify value MEDIUMBLOB;
```

both may not be necessary.  A more permanent fix might involve using the 'length=' parameters when the tables are created by airflow/models.py.